# Error: [object HTMLUnknownElement] when using "insertAdjacentHTML()" instead of "append"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser

Ive got this code where a HTML file element gets successfully injected into target page when a certain button is clcked:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("dd7975c81b0fac90f6bba640604bcb96").addEventListener("click", function () {
        injectElements_page();
    });
}

function injectElements_page() {
    var injectedStuff = document.createElement("element");
    fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('timer/timer.html'))
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
    injectedStuff.innerHTML = data;
    document.getElementById("section-07b699970f7ada007b2ff68ce1050eb1.header").append(injectedStuff);
    }).catch(err => {
    // handle error
});
}
```

But it is not recognizing a Timer in the same .js file:

```
function startTimer(duration, display, callback) {
    let timer = duration;
    let minutes;
    let seconds;
    let interval = setInterval(function() {
      minutes = ('00' + parseInt(timer / 60, 10)).slice(-2);
      seconds = ('00' + parseInt(timer % 60, 10)).slice(-2);
      display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
  
      if (--timer < 0) {
        callback();
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  const onTimerEnded = () => 
  // alertTimeOver(); // -> message when time is over
  
  window.addEventListener('load', function (){
    function () {
    const fiveMinutes = 60 * 0.24;
    const display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display, onTimerEnded);
//});
});
```

This is in the external HTML body (timer.html):

```
<div id="myAlertMsg">
        <div class="round-time-bar" data-style="smooth" style="--duration: 15;">
            <div></div><span class="timer_style" id="time">00:15</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried resolving this by switching from `append` to `insertAdjacentHTML` like so:

```
function injectElements_page() {
    var injectedStuff = document.createElement("element");
    fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('timer/timer.html'))
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
    injectedStuff.innerHTML = data;
    document.getElementById("section-07b699970f7ada007b2ff68ce1050eb1.header").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',injectedStuff);
    }).catch(err => {
    // handle error
});
}
```

But with this change from `append` to `insertAdjacentHTML` I get in the Page, where the timer should be injected, this error:

```
[object HTMLUnknownElement]
```

Now I know the timer works because if I inject the HTML some other way like this:

```
fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('timer/timer.html')).then(r => r.text()).then(html => {
    if (window.location.toString().includes("sysparm_domain=null&sysparm_domain_scope=null")) {
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', html);
   }
}
```

This way the timer actually works. But I want to load the timer when a certain button is clicked, not when a certain URL is loaded. I've been going around in circles and don't understand why this happens.

What am I doing wrong? What can be changed?
By the way, this is for a Google Chrome Extension and the Javascript is all inside the "foreground.js" file.

Comment: insertAdjacentHTML needs a string, not an object. Replace `injectedStuff` in ('beforeend', injectedStuff) with `data` or use append. Note that you can't add scripts via HTML, you need to use createElement('script') + appendChild.

Comment: I will try this but seems confusing (i'm still learning basic Javascript). If you'll post your suggestion as an answer I'll accept it if it works out.

Comment: It worked out replacing ```injectedStuff``` with ```data```. I don't get the Error: ```[object HTMLUnknownElement]``` But the script part for the timer to work eludes me. Timer still is not recognized. I will research about this and try. Thank you.